# Shorten time in following sql query which is taking 1 to 2 hours

Tags: sql-server

```
Update table1 set BD_COL=ltrim(rtrim(MAT_DRG) from table1  inner join table2 on
(([name] like '24_%' and Substring([name],4,len([name])=ltrim(rtrim(MAT_DRG)) and isnull(MAT_DRG,'') and itemtype='STD') 
or
([name] like '24/%' and Substring([name],4,len([name])=ltrim(rtrim(MAT_DRG)) and isnull(MAT_DRG,'') and itemtype='STD')
or
([name] like '24_%' and Substring([name],7,16)=ltrim(rtrim(MAT_DRG)) and  itemtype='STD')
or ltrim(rtrim(MAT_DRG))=[name])
)
```

Comment: Your query contains syntax error.

Comment: Optimize your table, optimize datatypes, add pre-processing so you don't have to use functions in your query, add indexes, etc.

Comment: Look at statistics io and query plan to see what' happening. Maybe adding an index will help

Comment: You must add some description for what you are trying to achieve, since this is not your real query but madeup sample query for this question. Your query does not make sense to me.

Comment: Mr  Vojtěch Dohnal I cant say my out put those 24% resembles Parts and itemtype are items

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you do not post your real query with real table names? Is it too long? There is an edit button and you can edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression like `Substring([name],4,len([name])=ltrim(rtrim(MAT_DRG))` hurts performance even index is created on name column. Consider create a computed column as `SubString(name, 4, len(name))` and create index on this new column.

Do the same for other expression and columns.